# Merging Two Tables and Calculating Amount (Currency Conversion)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table which contains the currency exchange rates and another one with converted amounts.

Currency Table
This table will have the daily rates of the currency. For the ease of mapping I have only included rates for one date.

```
Branch  Code    Rate       Date
A        0         1    30/10/2019
A        1       200    30/10/2019
A        2       300    30/10/2019
B        0         1    30/10/2019
B        1        10    30/10/2019
B        2        30    30/10/2019
```

Converted Amounts Table
This table will have the daily exchange details. For the ease of mapping I have only included transactions for one date.

```
Branch  Code     Amt      Date
A         0     1000    30/10/2019
A         1     2000    30/10/2019
A         2     3000    30/10/2019
A         2     4000    30/10/2019
A         2     5000    30/10/2019
A         0     6000    30/10/2019
B         0     7000    30/10/2019
B         0     8000    30/10/2019
B         0     9000    30/10/2019
B         2    10000    30/10/2019
```

Resultant Table

```
Branch  Code   Date        Amt   Branch Code   Rate   Total
A          0   30/10/2019  1000   A      0       1     1000
A          1   30/10/2019  2000   A      1     200   400000
A          2   30/10/2019  3000   A      2     300   900000
A          2   30/10/2019  4000   A      2     300  1200000
A          2   30/10/2019  5000   A      2     300  1500000
A          0   30/10/2019  6000   A      1       1     6000
B          0   30/10/2019  7000   A      1     200  1400000
B          0   30/10/2019  8000   A      1     200  1600000
B          0   30/10/2019  9000   A      1     200  1800000
B          2   30/10/2019 10000   A      2     300  3000000
```

I could only get the following resultant table.

```
Branch  Code    Date     Amt    Branch  Code    Rate    Total
A        0  30/10/2019  1000       A      0       1      1000
A        1  30/10/2019  2000       A      1     200    400000
A        2  30/10/2019  3000       A      2     300    900000
A        2  30/10/2019  4000       A      2     300   1200000
A        2  30/10/2019  5000       A      2     300   1500000
A        0  30/10/2019  6000       A      1       1      6000
B        0  30/10/2019  7000       A      1       1      7000
B        0  30/10/2019  8000       A      1       1      8000
B        0  30/10/2019  9000       A      1       1      9000
B        2  30/10/2019  10000      A      2     300   3000000
```

Query I use.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  converted_amounts_table t1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      (
        CASE WHEN code = '0' 
        AND branch = 'B' THEN '1' ELSE code END
      ) AS new_code, 
      branch, 
      date, 
      rate 
    FROM 
      currency_table
  ) t2 ON (
    t1.date = t2.date 
    AND t1.code = t2.new_code
  ) 
WHERE 
  t1.date >= '01-Jan-2019' 
  AND t1.date <= '30-Sep-2019'
```

Comment: This is not a complete question (yet), because you did not include the relevant data directly in the question.  Please _delete_ the image links, and instead include this information as _text_.

Comment: I have updated the tables. Please have a look.

Comment: Hi @SAMROX, here are some things I believe you should edit in your question:
"Note: There is a date column which I did not included" where ? In which table ?
What code did you try so far ?
It is not clear what you want to have as a result.

Comment: Hi Vboksic, I have updated the tables...

Comment: @SAMROX . . . You should show the query that you are using.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, I have added the query..

Comment: @somrox: your select does not have any try to get Total so I do not know what you want exactly. I am not sure but my demo looks too simple to help but you never know... Here is the demo I have done: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6981fa58bbeac0212086bd6bcfec1a0e

Comment: I think you are running across the filter you are using at WHERE condition. Please compare Date-to-dates. This is good article from Tom, might helpful https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=date-queries-using-between

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. What I'm trying to achieve is described below.

When the Branch = B and Code = 0, I need to get the Rate of Branch = A and Code = 1.

I did use a case statement but it only works for one date not for a date range. I will update that query as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the resultant table.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4d5401320bda5ad736070541d55d1d04

```
SELECT 
      t1.branch, 
      t1.date2, 
      t1.code, 
      t2.code, 
      t2.new_code, 
      t2.rate, 
      t1.amt, 
      t1.amt * t2.rate AS Total 
    FROM 
      converted_amounts_table t1 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 
          (CASE WHEN code = 1 THEN 0 ELSE code END) AS new_code, 
          branch, 
          date1, 
          code, 
          rate 
        FROM 
          currency_table 
        WHERE 
          branch = 'A'
      ) t2 ON (
        t1.date2 = t2.date1 
        AND t1.code IN (t2.new_code, t2.code)
      ) 
    WHERE 
      t1.date2 = '30 - Oct - 2019' 
      AND (
        t1.branch, t1.code, t2.code, t2.new_code, 
        t2.rate
      ) NOT IN (
        ('B', 0, 0, 0, 1), 
        ('A', 0, 1, 0, 200)
      )
```

Comment: Hi @SAMROX, first you are welcome for the demo. Second this part of code you do not need because it does nothing: `t1.date2 = '30 - Oct - 2019' AND` . Cheers!